# Function's argument is either of 3 types that all share 1 property in common, but their other properties vary depending on the type. Issues arise

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function that takes either of 3 types that all share 1 property in common, but their other properties vary:

```
private async processPredicates(
    routing: ActivityRouting[] | ActivityStepOptionsOverride[] | ActivityStepContentSource[]
) {
    for (const { predicate, ...block } of routing) {
        if (predicate == null) return block;
        else if (await this.callMethod(PREDICATES, predicate)) return block;
    }

    return null;
}
```

The property that all 3 types share is called `predicate`

```
export type ActivityRouting = {
    predicate?: string[];
    sideEffects?: SideEffect[];
    next?: Next;
};

export type ActivityStepOptionsOverride = {
    mode?: string;
    predicate?: string[];
};

export type ActivityStepContentSource = {
    reduce?: string;
    use?: string;
    predicate?: string[];
};
```

Now here's my problem - after adding the second and third type to processPredicates, the following function started giving me 2 errors:

```
   private async resolveRouting({
        routing,
        step,
        options,
        defaultNext,
    }: {
        routing?: ActivityRouting[];
        step: ActivityStep;
        options: ActivityStepOptions;
        defaultNext: Next;
    }) {
        await StepEvaluationContext.evaluate({ controller: this, step, options }, async () => {
            const leftoverRouting = routing && (await this.processPredicates(routing));

            if (leftoverRouting && leftoverRouting.sideEffects) {
                await Promise.all(
                    leftoverRouting.sideEffects.map(
                        async (sideEffect) => await this.callMethod(SIDE_EFFECTS, sideEffect)
                    )
                );
            }

            await this.callMethod(STEP_RESOLVERS, leftoverRouting?.next ?? defaultNext);
        });
    }
```

The errors are:

```
Property 'sideEffects' does not exist on type '{ sideEffects?: SideEffect[] | undefined; next?: Next | undefined; } | { reduce?: string | undefined; use?: string | undefined; } | { mode?: string | undefined; }'.
  Property 'sideEffects' does not exist on type '{ reduce?: string | undefined; use?: string | undefined; }'.ts(2339)
```

And

```
Property 'next' does not exist on type '{ sideEffects?: SideEffect[] | undefined; next?: Next | undefined; } | { reduce?: string | undefined; use?: string | undefined; } | { mode?: string | undefined; }'.
  Property 'next' does not exist on type '{ reduce?: string | undefined; use?: string | undefined; }'.ts(2339)
```

I imagine the error stems from the fact that the function `resolveRouting` doesn't know which of the 3 types `leftoverRouting`, so it just tells me that the property doesn't exist. I'm not quite sure how to handle that problem though.

Comment: What _should_ happen if the value passed doesn't have `next`? Maybe you should read e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the return type of `processPredicates` function has the union of all 3 types. It's not possible to access `leftoverRouting.sideEffects` without a [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it.

To solve it make `processPredicates` a generic function that returns the type being called instead. It would be the following:

```js
interface Activity {
  predicate?: string[];
}

export interface ActivityRouting extends Activity {
  sideEffects?: string[];
  next?: string;
};

export interface ActivityStepOptionsOverride extends Activity {
  mode?: string;
};

export interface ActivityStepContentSource extends Activity {
  reduce?: string;
  use?: string;
};
```

```js
async function processPredicates<T extends Activity>(
  routing: T[]
): Promise<Omit<T, 'predicate'> | null> {
  for (const { predicate, ...block } of routing) {
      if (predicate == null) return block;
      else if (await this.callMethod(PREDICATES, predicate)) return block;
  }

  return null;
}
```